# Seaborn - Change the X-Axis Range (Date field)

Tags: pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

how can I change the x-axis so that I begin on January 1 2022? I don't want to set the other side of the bound. The aim here is to create a YTD chart. Thanks! (Data type for the x-axis field 'Date_reported' is a Dtype datetime64[ns]) (ps: does anyone know why my figsize statement isn't working? I'm aiming for the 15 by 8 siz but it doesn't seem to work. [image]

```
sns.relplot(kind='line', data=df_Final, x='Date_reported', y='New_cases_Mov_avg',
                        hue='Continent', linewidth=1, ci=None)
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_style('ticks')
plt.xlabel("Date Reported")
plt.ylabel("New Cases (Moving Average)")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,8))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could define your figure and ax beforehand, set the `figsize` and then plot. Doing so, you have to go with `lineplot` instead of `relplot`.
`ax.set_xlim` will define the left boundary, `fig.autofmt_xdate` rotates the x labels.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,8))
sns.lineplot(data=df_Final, x='Date_reported', y='New_cases_Mov_avg',
                        hue='Continent', linewidth=1, ci=None, ax=ax)
sns.set_style("white")
sns.set_style('ticks')
ax.set_xlabel("Date Reported")
ax.set_ylabel("New Cases (Moving Average)")
ax.set_xlim(datetime.date(2022, 1, 1))
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Comment: Wonderful. Thank you! (I tried to edit your 'ax_set.xlim(datetime.date(2022, 1, 1))' to it's proper syntax for others. Thanks again!

Comment: you're welcome! oh thanks for pointing out that typo, I changed it.